# Angular - Http Interceptor not firing

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

For whatever reason I can't seem to figure out why my interceptor is not working. The code below is what I am using for my interceptor. I also have 2 other interceptors that work fine so I don't know why LoadingInterceptor below is not firing.

```
@Injectable()
export class LoadingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private loadingService: LoadingService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.showLoader();
    console.log('Intercept executed') // No log in the console shows up

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap(
        (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            this.hideLoader();
          }
        },
        (error: any) => {
          this.hideLoader();
        }
      )
    );
  }

  private showLoader(): void {
    console.log('Show Loader'); // no log in the console shows up
    this.loadingService.show();
  }

  private hideLoader(): void {
    console.log('Hide Loader'); // no log in the console shows up
    this.loadingService.hide();
  }
}

export const LOADING_PROVIDER: ClassProvider = {
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: LoadingInterceptor,
  multi: true
};
```

LoadingService in case it matters(LoadingService is working correctly).

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoadingService {
  private subject = new Subject<LoadingState>();

  constructor() {}

  loadingInit(): Observable<LoadingState> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }

  show() {
    this.subject.next(<LoadingState>{ show: true });
  }

  hide() {
    this.subject.next(<LoadingState>{ show: false });
  }
}
```

And here is core.module.ts

```
 @NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  providers: [
    LOADING_PROVIDER,
    RETRY_PROVIDER,
    HANDLE_ERROR_PROVIDER
  ]
})

export class CoreModule {}
```

app.mdoule.ts

```
 @NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, NotificationsComponent, LoaderComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [CoreModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: you should but the `CoreModule` in the `imports` array not in the providers.

Comment: Oh my.. That's what the problem was. Thank you!